# Linear sequences nth term exam question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

The nth term of a sequence is 4n + 1 where n is a positive integer.

a) Find an expression for the sum of the (n-1)th and nth terms of this sequence.

Give your answer in simplest form.

What I did:
 4n + 1 + (4n) = 8n + 1

b) The sum of two consecutive terms in the sequence is 70.

Work out the larger of the two terms.

8n + 1 = 70

8n = 69

Idk what to do for this question.

Thank You and help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the $(n-1)^{th}$ term of the sequence?

Comment: The $n^{th}$ term is $4n+1$ so the $(n-1)^{st}$ term is...?

Comment: If nth term is 4n+1, the next term is 4(n+1)+1...

Comment: Since your name references GCSEs: at GCSE level you're expected to be able to "check your working".  In this case, when $n=1$ and $n=2$ you have terms 5 and 9 in your sequence.  $5+9=14$, but for $n=2$ *your* answer of $8n+1$ gives $9$.  So by checking your working you know you've made a mistake.

Comment: Ok I will do that in future.

Answer (score 2):

You have done wrongly from the first question.

The $\left(n-1\right)$ term of the sequence is $4\left(n-1\right)+1=4n-3$. Therefore, the sum of the $n$th term and the $\left(n-1\right)$th term is $\left(4n+1\right)+\left(4n-3\right)=8n-2$

The second question is like that:
$$8n-2=70 \\ 8n=72 \\ n=9$$
So the larger term is $4n+1=4*9+1=37$

Comment: O thank you! :D I didn't realise my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

${t}_n\;+\;{t}_{(n-1)} = (4n+1)+(4(n-1)+1)$ $\\$
i.e 8n - 2 = 70 hence n= 9 the number are 33 , 37